# Registrar valor de formulário e somar com o valor do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, html5, formulário

Tenho uma dúvida, como faço pra somar o valor digitado do formulário com os dados que estão gravados dentro do banco de dados? A estrutura é mais ou menos essa.

No action do formulário ele me leva para a pagina altera.php

```
$p = new Produto();

$id = addslashes($_POST['id']);
$nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
$quantidade = addslashes($_POST['quantidade']);
$descricao = addslashes($_POST['descricao']);

$p->alterarProduto($id, $nome, $quantidade, $descricao);
```

A função alterarProduto está dentro de Produto.class.php e pertence ao objeto Produto(),
eu busco do banco de dados a quantidade de produtos pelo id associado na própria página altera.php

```
global $pdo;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = '$id'";
        $sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt = $sql->execute();
        foreach ($sql as $row){
            $row['nome'];
            $row['quantidade'];
            $row['descricao'];
        }
```

A sintaxe seria algo parecido com isso: $quantidade = $quantidade + $valorAtual, o problema que não estou conseguindo pegar os valores corretamente e fazer a soma.

Comment: Quais valores você não está conseguindo pegar corretamente?

Comment: Caso uma das respostas esteja correta, sugiro que marque como "aceita" para que sua dúvida possa ajudar outros usuários também

Answer (score 0):

Eu listo os produtos conforme anexo abaixo
[image: Listar]

ao clicar em editar ele me redireciona pra essa pagina buscando o nome e a quantidade de produtos, porém quando edito ele só substitui o valor, eu quero que ele pegue o valor 5 do banco de dados e some com o valor que o usuário digitar. Ex: 5 (valor BD) + 3 (valor digitado) = 8.
[image: Editar produto]

Answer (score 0):

Nunca utilize os valores diretamente em um sql, você deve utilizar a função [bindParam()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) para prever [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Para atualizar um valor somado à outro, você pode fazer direto no SQL:

```
    $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE produtos
        SET quantidade = (:quantidade + quantidade)
        WHERE id = :id');
    $query->bindParam(':quantidade', $quantidade, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
```

Porém, não esqueça de fazer as devidas validações dos campos antes de realizar o update.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, realmente era isso que estava faltando, se não for pergunta de mais essa sintaxe: PDO::PARAM_INT, ela é usada somente em valores inteiros? faz alguma diferença deixar de usa-lá, a pergunta pode ser meio besta, mas comecei a pouco tempo a estudar sobre PDO e fiquei curioso.

Comment: @Gilmarmh o terceiro parâmetro é opcional

Comment: Sempre que tiver dúvidas, você pode consultar a documentação oficial do PHP [clicando aqui](https://www.php.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Olá @Gilmarmh
Você precisa pegar o ID do que foi editado e rodar um SQL com "update" no Banco. Para ser bem simples, é pegar o dado novo e rodar uma query de Update com o novo valor.

A query ficaria algo como:

```
$sql = "Update produtos set quantidade = ".$quantidade." WHERE id = '$id'";
```

E roda o execute do mesmo jeito que você fez o select.

Vale dar uma consultada em: [W3Schools - PHP MySQL Update Data](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)